# Time_trans works with objects of class posixct only in R

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, posixct, shinyapps

I got the `Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only` when I run the program in `shiny`. And this is my code in `shiny`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)   # For nicer ggplot2 output when deployed on Linux
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Brush and double-click to zoom"),
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 300,
                      dblclick = "plot1_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE
                      ))),
             column(width = 6,
                    plotOutput("plot3", height = 300)
             )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Single zoomable plot (on left)
  ranges <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(sensor_online, aes(x= record_time, y= temperature)) +
      geom_point() +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y, expand = FALSE)
  })

  # When a double-click happens, check if there's a brush on the plot.
  # If so, zoom to the brush bounds; if not, reset the zoom.
  observeEvent(input$plot1_dblclick, {
    brush <- input$plot1_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)

    } else {
      ranges$x <- NULL
      ranges$y <- NULL
    }})}

  # -------------------------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And the `sensor_online` in the `ggplot` is from here :

```
#### 
# This script compute down time due to humidity and temperature out of spec
# It's denoted as out.spec.dt
# Data file is html file downloaded from Presidio
# Data gap could be found in the data file due to sensor break or Presidio server down.
# In this case the down time is denoted as sensor.dt
# assign interval for first row of record as 0. 2nd row's interval is
# delta between date/time of 2nd and first row.
#### 

require(XML)
require(ggplot2)
x = readHTMLTable(choose.files()) #read data from a file
str(x)
y<- x[[2]] #list element2 is the table that contain temperature and humidity data
require(data.table)
head(y)
e<- data.table(y)
str(e)
head(e)
setnames(e,c("record_time","temperature","temp.status","humidity","hum.status","comment")) # change column names
e<- transform(e, record_time= as.character(record_time), comment= as.character(comment),
              temperature= as.numeric(as.character(temperature)), 
              humidity= as.numeric(as.character(humidity))) 
#cannot convert factor to numeric by just "as.numeric(humidity)"
require(lubridate)
t<-dmy_hms(e$record_time)
sep.time<- IDateTime(t) #split "record_time" column into "idate" and "itime" columns
v<- cbind(e, sep.time) #add date and time columns to data table
v$weekdays<- wday(v$idate, label= TRUE)
v$hours<- hour(v$itime)
v$minutes<- minute(v$itime)
setkey(v, idate, hours, minutes) #sort the table in date->hours->minutes orders
#v<- v[(weekdays!="Sat")&(weekdays!="Sun")] #remove Sat and Sun data
v$clock.time<- dmy_hms(v$record_time)
# assign interval for first row of record as 0. 2nd row's interval is
# delta between date/time of 2nd and first row.
v$interval<- c(0, as.double(difftime(v$clock.time[-1], v$clock.time[-nrow(v)],
                                     units= "mins"))) #interval in second
v$day.age<- as.double(difftime(v$idate, v$idate[1],units= "days")) #for reference only
v$record.num<- seq(1,nrow(v), by= 1) #for reference only
#v[, record.num.original:= record.num]
hist(v$interval)

# rn= row number
# decide what extent of interruption is considered sensor down,
# in this script, it is "median(v$interval)*3"
sensor.down.rn<- which(v$interval> median(v$interval)*3) 
sensor.dt<- sum(v$interval[sensor.down.rn]) #dt= down time, in minutes
out.spec.rn<- which((v$temperature<20.5)|(v$humidity>72)|(v$temperature>27.5)|(v$humidity<33))

#refer to "2_down_time_Aug_flowchart.ppt" for the loop below
#the loop mainly leave out sensor.dt from out.spec.dt
out.spec.dt<- 0
for (i in 1:(length(out.spec.rn))) {
  if (i!= length(out.spec.rn)) {
    if ((out.spec.rn[i+1]-out.spec.rn[i])== 1) {
      out.spec.dt<- out.spec.dt+ v$interval[out.spec.rn[i]+1]
      v[(out.spec.rn[i]+1), Out.Spec.Dt:= out.spec.dt] #add downtime to Out.Spec.Dt column, "out.spec.rn[i]+1" row
    } else {
      if (v$interval[out.spec.rn[i]+1]< median(v$interval)*3) {
        out.spec.dt<- out.spec.dt+ v$interval[out.spec.rn[i]+1]
        v[(out.spec.rn[i]+1), Out.Spec.Dt:= out.spec.dt]
      }
    }    
  } else {
    if (v$interval[out.spec.rn[i]+1]< median(v$interval)*3) {
      out.spec.dt<- out.spec.dt+ v$interval[out.spec.rn[i]+1]
      v[(out.spec.rn[i]+1), Out.Spec.Dt:= out.spec.dt]
    }    
  }
}

sensor.dt
out.spec.dt
sensor_online<- e[which(!is.na(e$humidity)), ]
head(sensor_online)
str(sensor_online)
sensor_online$record_time<- dmy_hms(sensor_online$record_time)
ggplot(sensor_online, aes(record_time, temperature)) + geom_point()
```

What should I add in my `shiny` `server` so that don't have the `Error`?

Comment: The shiny app runs for me when I ignore your ````sensor_online```` code so the error is likely from your other code. Have you tried running your code outside of shiny to see if the error comes from there? Also try the ggplot in your server function outside of shiny, the error might be coming from there, since the ````times_trans```` function comes from ````scales```` I can't test your code because I don't know what goes into ````x = readHTMLTable(choose.files())````

Comment: stilestrigga95@gmail.com

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error, app runs just fine for me https://i.imgur.com/UT9IGkb.jpg

Comment: @Mr.Rlover but when I double-click to zoom in, it shows the Error, isn't?

Comment: no that doesn't happen either